# Jquery Contains and Not Contains Chaining

Tags: jquery, contains, jquery-chaining

Image i have table like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Adresse IP</td>
        <td class='tdSoap'>10.2.3.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zobi</td>
        <td class='tdSoap'>blabla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adresse</td>
        <td class='tdSoap'>NYC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want get the "NYC" value, by selecting the TR what has a TD with "Adresse", but NOT with "Adresse IP".

I already do what I want with this code :

```
$("table tr:has(td:contains('Adresse'))").not(":contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)").find("td.tdSoap").text();
```

But, I tried a lot with this kind of code, and never succeed :

```
$("table tr:has(td:contains('Adresse'):not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)')) td.tdSoap").text();
```

PS : "\u00a" is becaused of that http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3450

Comment: can you put td with id base like <td class='tdsoap' id='adress'> ?

Comment: Why not simply `:not(':contains(Adresse IP)')` ?

Comment: @Mahmood, i used this code on greasemonkey. So i cant modify the TDs.

Comment: @dsq, it's what i tried to used, but chained with contains("Adesse"). Acutally, I have a lot of TDs in my Table (not only 3 like in my example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps this:

```
$("table tr td:contains('Adresse')").not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)').next('.tdSoap').text();
```

why does this not work:(what you have)

```
$("table tr:has(td:contains('Adresse'):not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)')) td.tdSoap").text();
```

jQuery uses a right to left in a selector, so think this:

1. find all td.tdSoap
2. now find those that have not any 'Adresse\u00a0IP' - well none do inside the td.tdSoap
3. now find those that do have 'Adresse' - well none do inside the td.tdSoap
4. now has, combine those - still none INSIDE that td.tdSoap so nothing is selected.

Now, this also works taking out the "has" and added a next:

```
$("table tr td:contains('Adresse'):not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)')").next("td.tdSoap").addClass('myfirst');
```

However, run some performance metrics and see which of these is faster:

```
$('table').find('tr').find('td:contains("Adresse")').not(':contains("Adresse\u00a0IP")').next('.tdSoap').text();
$('table').find('.tdSoap').prev(':contains(Adresse)').not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)').next().text();
$("table tr td:contains('Adresse'):not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)')").next('td.tdSoap').text();
$("table tr:has(td:contains('Adresse'))").not(":contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)").find("td.tdSoap").text();
$("table tr td:contains('Adresse')").not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)').next('.tdSoap').text();
```

NOTE: those get the text of all of them if you have more "groups" of these, not sure you want all of them, but that is what you have.

EDIT: this works with or without the `&nbsp`

```
$('table').find('tr').find('td:contains("Adresse")').not(':contains("Adresse\u00a0IP")').not(':contains("Adresse IP")').next('.tdSoap').text();
```

Comment: FYI, I make the assumption you DO have &nbsp in the ip name thing - if you have some with, and some without that `&nbsp`, you will need to rework.  I tested these using 1.9.1 jQuery and 1.6.4

Comment: Thx Mark, for this answer. Makes more sense for me. But still dont understand why it works on Goram example : http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/2ycvN/

Comment: BTW, I tried with $("table tr td:contains('Adresse'):not(':contains(Adresse\u00a0IP)') + td.tdSoap") that is the same that next() (if i'm right), and it works too.

Comment: $("table tr:has(td:contains('Adresse'): td.tdSoap").text();

Comment: It IS weird to do, but putting in .next, .find etc is often faster than a large combined selector - seems counter intuitive, but the selector code works that way - run performance tests, try to limit as fast as possible the dom traversal.  That fiddle does not have the &nbsp in it - why I included an additional which filtered both.

Comment: Indeed, that's weird :) Thx Mark. I'll do some test to find the best way.

Comment: you are on the right track, test for performance, I used to a lot of combined selectors like that, but stopped when I had a performance issue and found the difference using .find(), .next() etc. to traverse a large complicate structure.  For example "#myid div.myclass" is slower than `$("#myid").find(".myclass")` making the assumption that only the div has that class.  and sometimes $(".myclass") is faster still using those assumptions - when it would seem using and id is "always use" it is NOT always faster in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the HTML, then this should do the trick:

```js
$('table tr:has(td:contains("Adresse"):not(:contains("Adresse IP"))) td.tdSoap').text()
```

Otherwise I'd advise trying what Mahmood says in the comments and giving it something specific to select on.

Comment: It's one of the variant I used. It's return nothing :(

Comment: In deed, it's working on your test-link. But I think Mark Schultheiss has the right answer.